# Android - Out of Memory Error due to starting a lot of Activities started

Tags: android

I have an application that implements somewhat like having a top page.
So like, i have this activities: 
`TopActivity` , `FirstActivity`, `SecondActivity`, `ThirdActivity` and `FourthActivity`.
Each activities has a button that when you press it, it will bring you back ti the `TopActivity`.

The way I implemented this one is every time that button is pressed, I start an activity, a new TopActivity. So, every time a top activity button is pressed, it always create a new activity. If I also will `finish()` the TopActivity when it goes to first, second and third, I can not go to TopPAge using back button. Are there itger ways to do this?

Any help is greatly apprieciated.

Comment: Why not `Fragments` of `Activity` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different [`Launch Mode`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) for you activities. The launch modes decides when and how to create a new Activity or reuse a previous one. 
The `singleTask` launch mode seems like it would do the trick for you:

> The system creates the activity at the root of a new task and routes
>   the intent to it. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a
>   call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.